# What does it mean for an object to be picklable (or pickle-able)?

Tags: python, pickle

Python docs mention this word a lot and I want to know what it means.

Comment: serializable.......

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It simply means it can be serialized by the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module. For a basic explanation of this, see [What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). [Pickling Class Instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) provides more details, and shows how classes can customize the process.

Answer (score 42):

Things that are usually not pickable are, for example, sockets, file(handler)s, database connections, and so on. Everything that's build up (recursively) from basic python types (dicts, lists, primitives, objects, object references, even circular) can be pickled by default.

You can implement custom pickling code that will, for example, store the configuration of a database connection and restore it afterwards, but you will need special, custom logic for this.

All of this makes pickling a lot more powerful than xml, json and yaml (but definitely not as readable)

Answer (score 17):

These are all great answers, but for anyone who's new to programming and still confused here's the simple answer:

**Pickling** an object is making it so you can store it long term, locked as it currently is (often to hard disk). A bit like Saving in a video game.

So anything that's actively changing (like a live connection to a database) can't be stored directly (though you could probably figure out a way to store the information needed to create a *new* connection, and that you could pickle)

Bonus definition: **Serializing** is packaging it in a form that can be handed off to another program.  **Unserializing** it is unpacking something you got sent so that you can use it

Answer (score 8):

***Pickling*** is the process in which the objects in python are converted into simple binary representation that can be used to write that object in a text file which can be stored. This is done to store the python objects and is also called as ***serialization***. You can infer from this what *de-serialization* or *unpickling* means.

So when we say an object is *picklable* it means that the object can be *serialized* using the pickle module of python.