# QuantLib in Python - cannot pickle 'SwigPyObject' object

Tags: python, spyder, quantlib, quantlib-swig

I complied QuantLib in Visual Studio 2017 and built the library under Release x64. Then I installed QuantLib Swig according to the instruction here: https://www.quantlib.org/install/windows-python.shtml

The directories in VS are set as in the screenshot:
[image]

Then I tested a plain vanilla European option using QuantLib which ran without error:

```
option = EuropeanOption(PlainVanillaPayoff(Option.Call,100),EuropeanExercise(Date(11,5,2021)))
```

However I cannot check the variable `option` in the IDE (I use Spyder) and saw error:

```
Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console.
```

The error message was:

```
cannot pickle 'SwigPyObject' object
```

I see the value of this variable is `EuropeanOption object of QuantLib.QuantLib module`.

**Version:**

```
Python: 3.8
Quantlib: 1.19
QuantLib-SWIG: 1.19
boost: 1_74_0
Spyder: 4.1.4
```

Would very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately not all Python objects can be explored through the Variable explorer. Only those that are [picklable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603581/what-does-it-mean-for-an-object-to-be-picklable-or-pickle-able) can be viewed, and the error message you posted above says `EuropeanOption` is not.

Furthermore, there's no workaround to avoid this issue because being picklable is a basic property of Python objects, and can't be changed by Spyder.

Comment: Thank you Carlos! This is clear. However is there any other IDE which will allow viewing the objects through variable explorer?

Comment: Not that I know of. However, we plan to improve the implementation of how objects are retrieved in the future, to allow non-picklable objects to be viewed as well.